# JQuery animate() function is delayed and runs slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, web

When I call a JQuery animate() call, the browser delays it for ~1 sec, and it then runs very slowly.

JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#header").load("global/html/header.html",function(){});
        $("#footer").load("global/html/footer.html",function(){});

        $(".navLI").hover(function() {
            $(this).animate({"backgroundColor": jQuery.Color(255, 51, 00, 255)}, 500);
            $(this).animate({"borderLeftColor": jQuery.Color(255, 51, 00, 255)}, 500);
        }, function () {
            $(this).animate({"backgroundColor": jQuery.Color(255, 255, 255, 255)}, 500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

All referenced libraries are imported

VIDEO: https://youtu.be/2NnDj_TGUNA

Comment: why using jQuery when you can do it using CSS3

Comment: just out of curiosity... what is `jQuery.Color` a plugin? Also what king of value is `(255, 255, 255, 255)` ? I think somethng's wrong. If you use Alpha the values shoud be `0-1` not `0-255`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, Google JQuery Color

Comment: OK, you google for Default Alpha opacity values in CSS ;)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , There are 2 acceptable formats. 0-1 is sometimes used. 0-255 is used mainly when converting from HEX to decimal value.

Comment: Thanks, but still... the 4th 255 seems totally odd. You think it works cause probably it converts 255 to 1

Comment: IF you read carefully the plugin docs. Alpha values are from 0 - 1: `Alpha()           // returns the "alpha" component of the color from ( Float from 0.0 - 1.0 )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS only:

```
.navLI{
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s;
          transition: 0.3s;
  background: rgba(255, 51, 255, 0.5);
}
.navLI:hover{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 51, 1);
}
```

Regarding your jQuery problem. you forgot to use `.stop()`

```
 $(this).stop().animate({"backgroundColor": jQuery.Color(255, 51, 0, 1)}, 500);
```

Comment: I would still prefer to use JQuery, as I will be using it for other things as well, and I would like to keep all the code in one format for easy editing.

Comment: @Jason don't use jQuery for what CSS can to it for you.